# How to create an in-memory icon for my unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, icons

I have a resource assembly that contains various strings, icons, and bitmaps that my application uses.

I have written a Resource Manager class that I would like to unit test.  I have managed to create unit tests that have in-memory strings (duh) and bitmaps but I am struggling with how to handle the icon resources.

Bitmaps can be easily created with just a height and width params but Icons seem to require a valid stream.

I've tried:

```
Icon icon = new Icon(new MemoryStream(), new Size(10, 15));
```

But this gives me the error "Argument 'picture' must be a picture that can be used as an icon".

Obviously I'm trying to write unit tests so want to avoid having to load a real icon from the file system.  Also the ResourceManager class is dealing with embedded resources within an assembly so I don't want to embed a real icon within my unit test assembly otherwise I'll be using similar code to facilitate the test which seems counter intuitive.

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Ben

Comment: Have you tried storing the icon as a binary value (or constant) and then writing the binary value to the stream?

Comment: I've just a had a look into that and for an icon chosen at random that created a byte array with length of 34494.  Not sure how I could get a valid byte array of sensible length to have in a constant.

Comment: From looking at the documentation I think you will have to provide a stream with real icon, which I believe contains some metadata as well. So it will be difficult to get away without using an embedded resource here.

Comment: Is that just the MSDN documentation you are referring to?  If not could you post a link?  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use one of the standard system icons? Like

```
Icon icon = System.Drawing.SystemIcons.WinLogo;
```

Comment: Hi, that's a good idea.  I wasn't aware of this collection of system icons.  This does allow me to have an in-memory icon but I am still having a few problems.

I can convert the WinLogo into a stream using the Icon.Save method but when I use this stream to re-create my icon using the icon constructor I get the same error message regarding 'valid picture'

Comment: Ok, it was because after the icon was written to the stream I neglected to reset the position to zero.  Works now! Thanks.